# How to implement data structure in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the following predicate `execute(actualState, instruction, nextState):-`
such that when executing with the instructions: `move, swap` , i have the following solutions:

```
?- executed(regs(1,4,*,+,2), swap(1,2), NS).
solution:
NS = regs(4,1,*,+,2)?;
no


?- executed(regs(1,4,3,6,+), move(4), NS).
solution:
NS = regs(1,4,3,6,6)?;
no
```

How can I implement it?

what I want it to do is that it has an initial state, an instruction and a final state "executed (actualState, instruction, nextState)" and what I want to do is pass it a list of registers as initial state, for example "`regs (1,2,3,4)`" and an instruction, for example, move and swap. swap (swap the position `X`, `X + 1`) and move (copy what is in `X` and deposit it in `X + 1`) and what I want it to return, as final state, are the examples described in the statement of my question.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear. What are these predicates supposed to achieve. Otherwise on possible answer is `executed(regs(1,4,3,6,+), move(4), regs(1,4,3,6,6)).` and `executed(regs(1,4,*,+,2), swap(1,2), regs(4,1,*,+,2))`

Comment: my predicate what I want it to do is that it has an initial state, an instruction and a final state "executed (actualState, instruction, nextState)" and what I want to do is pass it a list of registers as initial state, for example "regs (1,2,3,4) "and an instruction, for example, move and swap. swap (swap the position X, X + 1) and move (copy what is in X and deposit it in X + 1) and what I want it to return, as final state, are the examples described in the statement of my question.

Comment: *swap the position X, X + 1*. Since your example shows `swap` with two arguments, I assume this is really *swap the positions, X, Y*?

Comment: Effectively, that's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take the following approach. The key elements of this solution are:

- Use of `nth1/3` for considering an element of a list at a specified position
- `=../2` for mapping between a term with arguments and a list
- A "substitution" predicate that substitutes a value at specified position in a list with another

```
    subst([_|T], Y, 1, [Y|T]).
    subst([X|T], Y, N, [X|T1]) :-
        N #> 1,
        N1 #= N - 1,
        subst(T, Y, N1, T1).

    executed(AS, swap(X,Y), NS) :-
        AS =.. [regs|P],
        nth1(X, P, Xe),
        nth1(Y, P, Ye),
        subst(P, Ye, X, P1),
        subst(P1, Xe, Y, P2),
        NS =.. [regs|P2].

    executed(AS, move(X), NS) :-
        AS =.. [regs|P],
        nth1(X, P, Xe),
        X1 #= X + 1,
        subst(P, Xe, X1, P1),
        NS =.. [regs|P1].
```

If you are using SWI prolog, you'll need to include the clpfd library, `:- use_module(library(clpfd)).`. Also some Prologs, such as Ciao Prolog, does not have `nth1/3`. Ciao does provide, however, `nth/3` which has the same behavior, so it may be substituted.

Note that I'm using CLP(FD) here for more generality. If your system doesn't support CLP(FD) you can use `is` in place of `#=`, although it's less desirable.

Note that this solution works as long as the arguments indexing the registers are "in range". So it will fail on `executed(regs(1,2,+), move(3), NS).`. As an exercise, if this is required, you should try to enhance this solution to meet that need. It will help you to learn Prolog versus being given every detail of the solution.

Comment: I try to compile in the ciao GNU emacs environment and it gives me an error:
 ERROR: (lns 20-26) syntax error: operator expected after expression
executed( AS , move( X ) , NS ) :- AS =.. [ regs | P ] , nth1( X , P , Xe ) , X1
** here **
#= X + 1 , subst( P , Xe , X1 , P1 ) , NS =.. [ regs | P1 ] .
ERROR: (lns 31-34) syntax error: operator expected after expression
subst( [ X | T ] , Y , N , [ X | T1 ] ) :- N
** here **
#> 1 , N1 #= N - 1 , subst( T , Y , N1 , T1 ) .

Comment: @JerssonGA what Prolog are you using? As I mentioned in my answer if you're using SWI prolog then you need to include the CLPFD library as I noted. If it's a different prolog and you don't have CLPFD, you can make the solution less flexible (general) but substitute `is` for `#=`.

Comment: I was using swi-prolog, but now I am with ciao-prolog, when executing an instruction it gives me an error of: "{ERROR: codigo:nth1/3 - existence error: procedure:codigo:nth1/3 does not exist}", I understand that it must be declared, right? like " ```nth1(_,_,_).``` "

Comment: @JerssonGA no, you do not "declare" variables or predicates in Prolog. The problem is that Ciao does not have the `nth1/3` predicate. Why not use SWI Prolog? It's the most popular and supports a wide range of predicates in their libraries. If you must use Ciao, they may have `nth/3` but the indexing may assume that 0 is the index of the first list element, whereas `nth1/3` assume the first index is 1. My answer assumes it's 1. As an exercise, you should try to adapt it.

Comment: @JerssonGA I just checked an Ciao does have `nth/3` which you can use directly in place of `nth1/3`. Behavior should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution of swap. The key is term to list `=..`.
The rest is to dissect the list and put it back together.
Move is a piece of cake based on this answer and I left it "as an exercise"

```
:- use_module(library(lists)).
executed(H,swap(X,Y),Result):-
    H =.. [regs|TH],
    LL1 is X-1,
    LL2 is Y-X-1,
    length(TH,LL),
    LL3 is LL-Y,
    length(L1,LL1),
    length(L2,LL2),
    length(L3,LL3),
    append(L1,LI1,TH),[EX|LIX]=LI1,append(L2,LI2,LIX),[EY|L3]=LI2,
    flatten([regs,L1,EY,L2,EX,L3],LR),
    Result =.. LR.
```

Comment: Thanks, clarified my doubts, but the case of "move" I have to take into account if it is at the end of the records and I am stuck on it. :(

Comment: @JerssonGA if you have particular requirements on the arguments pertaining to corner cases like that, you need to specify that in your question. You don't mention it currently. Your examples don't cover it. I assume you mean a case like, `executed(regs(1,2,+), move(3), NS)`?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not clarifying it from the start