# implementation of copy in prolog

Tags: prolog

Given a list of regs `regs (1,2,3, ...)` what I want the code to do is to copy the position `X` to `X + 1`, I put some examples below. I have the following code in prolog:

```
    exe(EA, copy(X), ES):-
    EA =.. [reg|TH],
    LL1 is X+1,
    length(TH,LL),
    LL2 is LL+X+1,
    length(L1,LL1),
    length(L2,LL2),
    append(L1,LI1,TH),[EX|L2]=LT1,
    flatten(reg[L1,EX,L2], LR),
    ES=.. LR.
```

what i want to show me as a result is:

```
?- exe(reg(1,2,3,4), copy(2), ES).
result:
?- ES=reg(1,2,2,4)

?- exe(reg(4,6,2,9), copy(1), ES).
result:
?-ES=reg(4,4,2,9).

?- exe(reg(1,2), copy(2), ES).
result:
false
```

I think the code is wrong

Comment: Why don't you use actual lists? Like `reg([1,2,3])`?

Comment: I pass him a list of numbers or characters and what I want to achieve is to show me what I explain in the statement.

Comment: I think this is the same assignment: [Hot to implement data structure in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61639909/how-to-implement-data-structure-in-prolog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to split up your goal into multiple aspects, like: getting the element at position X (nth_element), then try to implement a predicate overwriting a particular value. Below is code that works as you expect. It basically traverses lists in the Prolog-"standard" way.

```
% Get the nth element of a list, indices starting at 1
nth_element([X|_], 1, X) :- !.
nth_element([_|Xs], N, R) :-
    M is N - 1,
    nth_element(Xs, M, R).

% Overwrites the N-th position in a list by a new element
% Indices starting with 1
% overwrite(List, N, Element, New_List) :-
% overwrite([], _, _, []) :- !.
overwrite([_|Xs], 1, Y, [Y|Xs]) :- !.
overwrite([X|Xs], N, Y, [X|Ys]) :-
    M is N - 1,
    overwrite(Xs, M, Y, Ys).

exe(EA, copy(X), Es):-
    EA =.. [reg|TH],
    nth_element(TH, X, Element),
    Y is X + 1,
    overwrite(TH, Y, Element, New),
    Es =.. [reg|New].
```

Comment: Ciao Prolog has `nth/3` as a built-in, so no need for `nth_element/3` here. Additionally, you should constrain N in your `overwrite/4` predicate, second clause to enforce `N > 1`. The cut (`!`) serves as a bit of a band-aide against that constraint being missing.